# How do I flash and prepare an ASUS Zenfone 2 Laser for custom ROM installation?

Tags: custom-roms, installation, rom, twrp

I am tired of the original ROM on my phone and I'll install the resurrection ROM.

I have the zip, but if I am not wrong I need to first do 3 things:

-get root access

-install TWRP

-and adb

Am I right?

I am still in the process of understanding how it works.

Where do I get these files and instructions? 
I have found some links, but none of them seems to be easy and well-explained.

Thanks!

Comment: link xda: https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone-2-laser

Comment: thanks a lot. I am confused though. I need to use:

-1st: twrp-3.0.2.0-Z00E-MM

-2nd: ZE500KL_BootloaderUnlock

-3rd the super Su.


all of this using the terminal (since I am using ubuntu).

Can't I just copy these and use the terminal off my phone to mount the above mentioned files?

Comment: I have tried flashing only through phone[I haven't tried through terminal or command prompt]. In my redmi 1s, I've flashed miui_root zip, then flashed twrp zip, then installed cyanogenmod rom zip. Completed. I think XDA have descibed everything for installation.

Comment: I cant get it work via the phones terminal. Basically the official asus unlock apk wont unlock the bootloader either.

I am trying to use the website you gave me, but when it fastboot mode...the terminal of my PC cant find the device. It can only find the device when it is not in fastboot mode.

It simply says "List of devices attached"..and the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need root access on your stock ROM. The step is:
     1. Unlock your phone ROM using official APK or other means (ASUS unlock APK was known to be buggy)
     2. Install TWRP using ADB
     3. Flash custom ROM using TWRP

Your warranty will be void and you might get your phone bricked.

Detailed guide:

1. Install ADB on your PC c:\adb
2. Copy TWRP recovery and ROM zip file to adb folder
3. In your Phone set development option on, enable USB debugging
4. Unlock your phone using official ASUS APK
5. Connect your phone to PC, run cmd on c:\adb ".\adb devices" confirm device connected
6. Run cmd: .\adb reboot-bootloader
7. Run cmd: .\fastboot devices, confirm device connected in fastboot mode
8. Flash TWRP: .\fastboot flash recovery twrprecoveryfile
9. Enter recovery mode
10. Flash custom ROM using TWRP